# Applitools.EyesSetViewportSizeException : Could not set required viewport size. Seems like a rounding error

Tags: c#, applitools

I'm trying to use Applitools ultrafast grid in .NET and keep getting this error.  I'm just trying to run their c# example code from their website:
https://applitools.com/docs/topics/overview/overview-writing-tests-with-vg.html

```
Result StackTrace: 
at Applitools.Selenium.EyesSeleniumUtils.SetViewportSizeAttempt3(Logger logger, IWebDriver driver, Size requiredSize, Size& actualViewportSize)
at Applitools.Selenium.EyesSeleniumUtils.SetViewportSize(Logger logger, IWebDriver driver, RectangleSize size)
at Applitools.Selenium.VisualGrid.VisualGridEyes.EnsureViewportSize_()
at Applitools.Selenium.VisualGrid.VisualGridEyes.Open(IWebDriver webDriver)
at Applitools.Selenium.Eyes.Open(IWebDriver driver)
at ApplitoolsHackathon2020.ModernVisualAITests.ModernVisualAITests.CrossDeviceElementTest() in HelloWord.cs:line 90
Result Message: Applitools.EyesSetViewportSizeException : Could not set required viewport size. Seems like a rounding error. Actual viewport size: {Width=800, Height=599}.
```

This is my setup

- Selenium Web Driver v3.141
- ChromeDriver v81.0.4044.13800
- Eyes.Sdk.Core v2.29.0
- Eyes.Selenium v2.29.0
- NUnit v3.11.0
- NUnit3TestAdaptor v3.15.1
- .NET 4.7.2

Anyone ever come across this and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

With Matt's help, it turns out I was getting this error because I had a custom scaling factor set in my display settings on the machine I was trying to run this on.  Turning that off and making sure the windows scaling level was set to 100% fixed this issue.

https://www.lifewire.com/using-windows-10-display-scaling-4587328

Answer (score -1):

This is Matt and I work on the Applitools support team. I see you're running into an issue with setting the Viewport Size in your .NET tests.

In this case, we'd typically ask for more information as well as verbose logging. Unfortunately, the logs will contain your API key so we can't have you post them here. Could you please open up a support ticket [here](https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)? Then, I'll be able to grab the required information and help you resolve this issue.

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: Hi Matt.  Actually I have opened a ticket, but haven't heard back since this morning.  I can post the ticket number here if you want.